# Joomla: onContentAfterSave not triggered for articles

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm developing a Joomla plugin with onContentAfterSave event to send an email after saving a new articles.

the event are triggered when i save a new menu item or a new category.
but not for new article.

> Joomla! 3.7.5

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew){ 
    $link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute(  $article->id,  $article->catid ));

    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $sender = array( 
        $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),
        $config->get( 'fromname' ) 
    );
    $mailer->setSender($sender);


    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $recipient = $user->email;

    $recipient = array($recipient);
    $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

    $body   = '<p>Bonjour</p>'
              .'Un nouveau <a href="'.$link.'">article</a> a été ajouté.';
    $mailer->isHtml(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';

    $mailer->setSubject('Nouveau article - BBN Times');
    $mailer->setBody($body);


    $send = $mailer->Send();

    if ( $send !== true ) {
        echo 'Error sending email: ';
    } else {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onContentAfterSave` is triggered by the Joomla core, and not by the extension's model, which means it should be triggered by any content saving.

I can think of 2 reasons why it is not triggered in your case:

- You have a condition in your constructor checking for the extension type and only allowing certain extensions to use that event (or somewhere else in your plugin).
- You have an error in the code above.

Comment: My plugin work good for all type (menu, category...) but not for article type.  Actually I use this condition  
if($isNew and in_array($context, array('com_content.article', 'com_content.form')))